# How to delete a line of text in python (minimal reproducable example)

Tags: python

The code I have used to delete a line from a file is deleting everything in the text file instead of the line that includes the name I input. Is there a fix for this, if so please could it be demonstrated?

```
def playerMenu():
    runningplayer = True
    while runningplayer == True:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print("\n====================================================")
        print("************Welcome to The Player Menu**************")
        print("====================================================")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        choice = input('''
========================================================

    A: Add Player & Score
    B: Delete Player
    C: View Scores
    D: Back To Main Menu
    E: Exit Menu

========================================================
\nPlease select what you wish to do: ''')

        #This ELIF statement will allow the user to write the name and score of the player.
        if choice == "A" or choice == "a":
            save_name = input('Enter your name. ').title()
            save_score = input('Enter your score. ')
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
            text_file.write("\n" + save_name + ' | ' + save_score + "\n")
            text_file.close()
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
            whole_thing = text_file.read()
            print (whole_thing)
            text_file.close()
            
        #This ELIF statement will allow the user to delete a player from the text file.
        elif choice == "B" or choice == "b":
            print("These are the current players and their score")
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
            whole_thing = text_file.read()
            print (whole_thing)
            text_file.close()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            save_delete = input("Please enter the name of the player you wish to delete: ")
            with open("highscores.txt", "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            with open("highscores.txt", "w") as f:
                for line in lines:
                    if line.strip("\n") != save_delete:
                        f.write(lines)
                        print(lines)
```

Comment: It looks like the format of the save file is `<name>|<score>` but you are just comparing the name. So, for example, "john" will never equal "john|1000". You can try `line.startswith(save_delete)`.

Comment: Or `line.startswith(save_delete + '|')` since you don't want to delete Bertha's score when you're trying to delete Bert's

Comment: Try `if line.split(' | ')[0] != save_delete:`

Comment: Hi there. We don't use `[Solved]` title hacks here. Please either accept an answer below (by ticking it) or write a self-answer and accept/tick that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took you Option B section code and modified it a little. Then, I included the delimitating character in the name of the line that needs to be deleted (to ensure that the whole name is being taken into account).

My test text file's contents looked like this:
bert|10\nbertha|9\nsam|8\nben|8\nhayley|6

My test code looks like this:

```
import time

print("These are the current players and their score")
text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
whole_thing = text_file.read()
print(whole_thing)
text_file.close()
time.sleep(0.3)
save_delete = input("Please enter the name of the player you wish to delete: ") + "|"
print(f"save_delete = {save_delete}")
with open("highscores.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines)
with open("highscores.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        if not(line.startswith(save_delete)):
            f.write(line)
```

If i run this, and choose te delete "bert", it only deletes bert (and not bertha as well). My text file's content results in:
bertha|9\nsam|8\nben|8\nhayley|6

Comment: Hi @skaedian when I used this code it gave me the following results for some reason, and when I view the file, Tom is still there.

Please select what you wish to do: b
These are the current players and their score

Tom | 54

Adam  | 5

Hamza | 69

Please enter the name of the player you wish to delete: Tom
save_delete = Tom|
['\n', 'Tom | 54\n', '\n', 'Adam  | 5\n', '\n', 'Hamza | 69\n']

Comment: Apologies, you can comment out the 13th line in my example. If you open the text file, Tom would have been deleted. I tested it now with your values.
EDIT: Also, do not put a space between the name and the "|".